# Can a USB drive be used as a security key to unlock a Ubuntu PC?

Tags: usb, security

I am currently looking to switch from Windows 10 to Ubuntu but I still want to use the security key I already have for unlocking my PC. Windows has a software called USB Raptor but this is not on Linux. I found this [article](https://medium.com/@abhattacharyea/use-your-usb-as-security-key-in-linux-e19b179d4b5c) showing how to do a similar thing but I want to make sure this still works or if there is a better way as it is 6 years out of date.